# Android: Visual version of Button.performClick

Tags: android

I know that I can trigger the OnClickListener.onClick of a Button manually in code by calling performClick, but that doesn't seem to make it visually appear as it's been clicked.  I'm looking for a way to manually make a button appear as if it's been clicked.  Do I need to manually change the background drawable and invalidate (and then change it back again on a Handler.postDelayed call), or is there a more framework-y way of doing this?

**EDIT**

I know how to make the button have different drawables to appear pressed when the user initiates the press.  The question is this:

*Is there a simple way to make a button appear pressed programmatically when not physically pressed by the user?*

**SOLUTION**

I just subclassed Button and made the button aware of it's normal background as a StateListDrawable and the Drawable that is used as the pressed state.  I expose a method that manually sets the background to the "pressed" drawable, and I use Handler.postAtTime to have it return to it's normal background so it can be used as a regular button again when I'm done.

Answer (score 4):

Although this question is very old, I figured I'll still answer it. You don't need to subclass the View. First call `performClick()`, visual cue won't last long, but then you can set the button's pressed state via `view.setPressed(true);` and then reset it a couple of milliseconds later like this.

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        view.setPressed(false);
    }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya, you have to create 2 drawables. One for pressed state and other for normal state.

Then you will have to create an xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
     android:state_pressed="true"
     android:drawable="@drawable/focused_drawable" />
    <item
     android:state_pressed="false"
     android:drawable="@drawable/unfocused_drawable" />
</selector>
```

Place this xml inside your drawable folder. You can also add focused state as

```
android:state_focused="true"
```

Then inside your layout which is used by your activity, give inside your button tag:

```
android:background="@drawable/your xml file name"
```

Comment: That's not the question.  I know how to use different drawables for button states.  The question is: How do I get the button to appear to be in the pressed state temporarily (as if it was clicked) from code.  I want to make buttons look like they've been pressed, and I want to be able to do this in code (not just when the button is physically pressed by the user).

Comment: I just did it manually, setting the background to simulate the "pressed" look and then on a timer (using a Handler) to set the button back to its normal StateListDrawable.  The solution is posted above if you're interested.